# Kafka Consumer stop consuming after a while with Kerberos authentication

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, kerberos

My java-spring application was consuming messages successfully from kafka0.9.0.0. but I moved to kafka0.10.2.0 which is there with Kerberos Authentication. So on this new kafka0.10, when I start my consumer application, it establishes kerberos authentication and consumes well. But after a while(uncertain time sometime 6 hours, 20 hours, 80 hours) it will stop consuming messages. Once I restart the application, it will process all non-consumed messages, consume for sometime and again stops. I don't get this weird scenario of consumer/kafka/kerberos. Can someone help me with how can my application keep consuming continuously? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without the actual error messages, your question is just a call to opinions and wild guesses.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter, stop consuming is not an error so there won't be any error message.